# Finding how relevant a text is, given a whitelist and blacklist of words/phrases

Tags: search, filter, machine-learning, document-classification

This is a case of me wanting to search for something online but not knowing what it's called.

I have a collection of job descriptions in text files, some only a sentence or two long, most a paragraph or two. I want to write a script that, given a set of rules, will notify me when it finds a job description I would want.

For example, lets say I am looking for a job in PHP programming, but not a full-time position and not a designing position. So my "rule book" could be:

```
want: PHP
want: web programming
want: telecommuting
do not want: designing
do not want: full-time position
```

What is a method I could use to sort these files into a "pass" (descriptions that match what I'm looking for) and a "fail" (descriptions are not relevant)? Some ideas I was considering:

- Count the occurrences of the phrases in the text file that are also in my "rule book", and reject those that contain words that I do not want. This doesn't always work, though, because what if a description says "web designing not required"? Then my algorithm would say "That contains the word `designing` so it is not relevant" when it really was!
- When searching the text for phrases that I do and do not want, count phrases within a certain Levenshtein distance as the same phrase. For example, `designing` and `design` should be treated the same way, as well as misspellings of words, such as `programing`.
- I have a large collection of descriptions that I have looked through manually. Is there a way I could "teach" the program "these are examples of good descriptions, these are examples of bad ones"?

Does anyone know what this "filtering process" is called, and/or have any advice or methods on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have a *text classification* or *document classification* problem.  This is a specific case of *binary classification*, which is itself a specific case of *supervised learning*.  It's well studied problem, there are many tools to do it.  Basically you give a set of good documents and bad documents to a learning or training process, which finds words that correlate strongly with positive and negative documents and it outputs a function capable of classifying unseen documents as positive or not.  Naive Bayes is the simplest learning algorithm for this kind of task, and it will do a decent job.  There are fancier algorithms like Logistic Regression and Support Vector Machines which will probably do a somewhat better, but they are more complicated.

To determine which variants words are actually equivalent to each other, you want to do some kind of stemming.  The Porter stemmer is a common choice here.